# Distance between miller planes for face centered cubic and body centered cubic?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Can someone confirm if this equation still applies to fcc and bcc crystals? $$  {\displaystyle d_{\ell mn}={\frac {a}{\sqrt {\ell ^{2}+m^{2}+n^{2}}}}}$$
If so, can someone outline a quick proof? I can see how this equation applies to simple cubic, but do not see how it applies to fcc crystals.

Comment: In the context of x-ray diffraction, one would say that the 001 reflection is forbidden and one designates the first reflection as 002. So these are not real Miller indices to describe surface orientations etc, but they describe sets of planes with a distance $a/2$.

Comment: @Pieter But is this formula correct in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, for cubic systems this is correct. You asked for a proof, and that can be done with Pythagoras I think. Or some linear algebra.